# selectionModel and selectedRows used selected rows but PyQt4.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x12xxxxxx

Tags: python, pyqt, selectionmodel, qmodelindex

```
  def listedensecilensatirlar(self):
      adada = self.ui.tableWidget.selectionModel().selectedRows()
      print adada
```

I have chosen the line in each row I want to achieve but the model did not read the index. I choose what I want to get as text data contained in rows.

This is a picture of my problem: i.stack.imgur.com/APFPl.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the text from the items in the selected rows, you could try this:

```
    indexes = tablewidget.selectionModel().selectedRows(column)
    for index in sorted(indexes):
        row = index.row()
        rowtext = []
        for column in range(tablewidget.columnCount()):
            rowtext.append(tablewidget.item(row, column).text())
        print(rowtext)
```

But note that [selectedRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) only get rows where *all* items are selected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer on the top, but try this one too.

```
indexRows = table.selectionModel().selectedRows()
for indexRow in sorted(indexRows):
    row = indexRow.row()
rowText = table_model.item(row, column=number).text()
print(rowText)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 0  # number of columns
items = self.ui.tableWidget.selectionModel().selectedRows(num)
row_text = [item.data() for item in items]
```